# Retrofit + OkHTTP with EBay's Inventory API

Tags: java, rest, retrofit, okhttp, ebay-api

I'm trying to execute the following two requests using [EBay's Inventory API](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/methods):

**POST:**  `bulkUpdatePriceQuantity` (create new listing)

**PUT:**  `createOrReplaceInventoryItem` (update price/quantity of listing) using

I'm fairly new to `Retrofit` and `OKHTTP` and was wondering if someone could post a simple example of how to create a new listing and update price/quantity of an existing listing.

I've spent a couple of days reading about `Retrofit` and `OKHTTP` and it seems very confusing. Like I don't understand where/how to add the EBay authorization token and how to pass the data to EBay (such as the new price/quantity or the details of a new listing).

So far this is what I've come up with for `Retrofit`:

```
public interface RetrofitEBaySellAPIService {

@Headers("X-EBAY-C-PACKED-EXAMPLE:   Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN_GOES_HERE>")
@POST("/bulk_update_price_quantity")
// https://api.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/bulk_update_price_quantity
Call<List<Task>> getTasks();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) // error: GsonConverterFactory cannot be resolved
        .build();

RetrofitEBaySellAPIService service = retrofit.create(RetrofitEBaySellAPIService.class);

Response response = service.getClientList("").execute();


}
```

And this is what I've come up with for `OKHTTP`:

```
public class OKHTTPPostExample  {


public OKHTTPPostExample()
{
}


public static final MediaType JSON
= MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

 public String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    String header = "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN_GOES_HERE?>";
    Headers headerbuild = Headers.of(header);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .headers(headerbuild)
            .build();


    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {

        return response.body().string();

    } 
}

 public String revisePriceAndQuantity(String sku) {
    return "{
        'requests' : [
        { 
        'sku' : 'SKU_STRING',
        "shipToLocationAvailability" :
        { 
        'quantity' : 'integer'
        }";




}




}
```

However, in both cases I'm getting numerous errors. I've read about both technologies for hours (my head is spinning) but I do not understand it clearly.

If someone could post a simple example of how to do both of these operations I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have developer account to check that it actually works but here is an example of bulkUpdatePriceQuantity

```
package example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.HeaderMap;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public class Runner {

    //DTOs
    public static class Offer {
        public Integer availableQuantity;
        public String offerId;
        public Price price;
    }

    public static class ShipToLocationAvailability {
        public Integer quantity;
    }

    public static class Price {
        public String currency;
        public String value;
    }

    public static class Request {
        public List<Offer> offers = null;
        public ShipToLocationAvailability shipToLocationAvailability;
        public String sku;
    }

    public static class Response {

        public String offerId;
        public String sku;
        public Integer statusCode;

    }

    public static class RequestBody{
        public List<Request> requests;
    }

    public static class ResponseBody{
        public List<Response> responses;
    }


    //api interface
    public static interface RetrofitEBaySellAPIService {

        @POST("/bulk_update_price_quantity")
        Call<ResponseBody> bulkUpdatePriceQuantity(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers, @Body RequestBody object);
    }


    //entry point
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        /**
         * request should be initialized.
         * you can do it by creating all necessary objects manually
         * or by deserializing the object from json like this
         * RequestBody request = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, RequestBody.class);
         * 
         * where jsonString is a string that contains json representation of your request body
         * 
         */
        RequestBody request = null; 

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RetrofitEBaySellAPIService service = retrofit.create(RetrofitEBaySellAPIService.class);
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        //token should hold a valid active token
        String token = null;
        //put all the headers you need in that map
        headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        ResponseBody response = service.bulkUpdatePriceQuantity(headers, request).execute().body();

    }

}
```

You need to have converter-gson, gson and retrofit in your classpath

Here is a fragment from my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope it helps